# Any real normal matrix can be decompsed into two real symmetric matrices, with one invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition

Any real normal matrix can be decompsed into two real symmetric matrices, with one invertible?

I know that each complex matrix can be decomposed into two complex symmetric matrices, with one invertible? How to do the real case?

Comment: What is meant by "decompose"? Product? Or something else? And do you mean normal complex matrices in the second statement?

Comment: Wow, you acknowledged an answer that doesn't help you at all. Respect.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since you know how to do it for complex: $A=B+iC+D+iE$, where $B+iC$ and $D+iE$ are symmetric (with real and complex parts separated) and at least one is invertible. Since $A$ is real, this implies $C=D=0$. So the result follows for real normal $A$.

Comment: The sum of two symmetric matrices is symmetric. So, if "decompose" meant the sum, OPs theorem would imply that every complex matrix is symmetric.

Comment: @amsmath: good point, I assumed as a sum (and answered irrespective of what $A$ needs to satisfy, just that the logic would carry over to reals).

Comment: Well, it's OP's fault if they don't specify what they mean by "decompose".